# Find a net $(x_{\lambda})$ in $\Omega_0$ which converges to $\omega_1$ in $\Omega$.

Tags: general-topology

**Definition** $(x_{\lambda})$ converges to $x \in X$ provided for each neighborhood U of x, there is some $\lambda_{0} \in \Lambda$ such that $\lambda \geq  \lambda_{0}$ implies $x_{\lambda} \in U$

Recall that $\Omega$ denotes the set of ordinals $\leq \omega_1$.

In the Ordinal space, recall that $\omega_1 \in cl(\Omega_0)$ where $\Omega_0=\Omega-\{\omega_1\}$.

**Problem** Find a net $(x_{\lambda})$ in $\Omega_0$ which converges to $\omega_1$ in $\Omega$. (But this isn't when I worked with natrurals numbers, could you give an idea?)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the topology you're using on $\Omega$ is the usual order topology. $\Omega_0$ (and indeed any nonzero ordinal, and indeed any linearly ordered set) is a directed set. The identity function $\Omega_0\to\Omega_0$ can serve as the net you want.

By the way, I believe $\Omega$ is more commonly used to denote what you call $\Omega_0$.

Comment: Munkres uses $\Omega$ for $\omega_1$ and $\overline{\Omega}=\omega_1+1 = \{\alpha: \alpha \le \omega_1\}$. I wished he'd stuck to standard notations...